# What is the average length of a line inside the unit square?

Tags: probability, geometric-probability, sampling-theory

This question lies in the chapter exercise of chapter 14 Sampling of book: Fundamentals of Computer Graphics by Peter Shirley and Steve Marschner.

Although this is not mentioned in the question but I assume our lines are random and are uniformly distributed.

As per my current knowledge the average length here means the expected value of a function f(r, theta) which gives the length of a line (r, theta) (the line is in **normal-angle space**) inside the unit square [0, 1]×[0, 1]. It is possible to find such function but I am not getting what **probability distribution function** to use in this case.

Comment: You must be explicit as to how the random lines are chosen, as there are several ways.  One could be choosing two points anywhere on the boundary with a uniform probability.  Another is to choose a point *within* the square with a two-dimensional uniform probability and then the angle uniformly between $0$ and $\pi$.  And there are yet others...

Comment: Sorry, meant to type ill-defined. This is related to Bertrand’s paradox. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: Edited: “Random and uniformly distributed” is ill defined, There are lots of ways to pick a line randomly. Pick a point and a slope. Pick two points on the boundary. Pick two points anywhere in the square.

Comment: Bertrand’s Paradox is that there are three ways to pick a chord on a circle, and each gives different probabilities.

Comment: @Jitendra Singh, unfortunately the answer key isn't available. But a hint for the answer verification is given, that is to generate 10 million random lines inside a unit square and average their lengths inside the square.

Comment: @David G. Stork, actually there is a section 14.4.4 in the same chapter titled "Example: Choosing Random Lines in the Square", there they have used function-inversion method to find the values (r, theta) in normal-angle space corresponding to (e1, e2) in xy Cartesian space. In this section they specified the problem as 'finding uniform random points in (r, theta) space that correspond to lines in square'. As the question haven't described much, thus I felt specifying 'random and uniformly distributed' would be a good description.

Comment: But you cannot answer the question *unless* you specify the sampling method.  Impossible.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, thanks for the Bertrand's Paradox, I will study over it. And to be specific, I want to work over the normal-angle space, where the line is described as the length of the perpendicular from origin to the line, and angle this perpendicular makes with the x-axis.